# Change locale in Symfony Validator Component

Tags: symfony, slim

I'm using [Symfony Validator component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html) with Slim, and I want to change english messages with another language.

How can I choose the language if I don't use Symfony?

Answer (score 0):

Before you do any validations, in the controller, you can change the locale using this:

```
$this->get('translator')->setLocale('new_locale');
```

This allows you to force the locale of the translator. Important: You need a container object to get the translator if you want to change the locale in a different place.

Comment: i don't have $this->get('service_name') in Slim. I tried to create a service in container and change locale but doesn't work

Comment: I'm not sure if the validator component is validating with slim translator but I leave you here a guide to change its locale:

http://nesbot.com/2012/6/26/multilingual-site-using-slim